# convergence of sequence of optimization problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, optimization

I have a sequence of minimization problem:
\begin{align}
P_n: \min_{x} &\quad f(x) \nonumber\\
\text{s.t.}& \quad w_n x \leq 1\nonumber
\end{align}
with $f(x)$ a strictly convex function over $x$. Denote $x_n^*$ as the optimal solution to Problem $P_n$. My question is if I have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}w_n=w_0$, can I say $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n^*=x_0^*$, where $x_0^*$ is the optimal solution of
\begin{align}
P_0: \min_{x} &\quad f(x) \nonumber\\
\text{s.t.}& \quad w_0 x \leq 1\nonumber
\end{align}

Comment: "the solution" isn't properly defined unless you have additional conditions that force the solution to be unique.  It's relatively easy to construct examples where there is a non-unique optimal solution in the limit and unique optimal solutions to the $n$th problem that do not converge or that converge to a particular optimal solution that might not be the $x_{0}^{*}$ that you want.

Comment: No, it is not true in general cases. You need some assumptions on $f$.

Comment: @YuhangChen Thanks. Could you please provide me some hints or some related references? What assumptions should there be?

Comment: @Brian Borchers Thanks very much for your comments. I modified my question and assume f(x) a strictly convex problem, such that the solution of Pn and P0 is unique. For this case, does the conclusion hold? how to prove it?

Comment: Having $f(x)$ strictly convex still isn't enough to ensure that the problem has a unique solution for all $w_{n}$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I can not see why strictly convex is not enough. Could you provide me some counter example? And what condition you think can guarantee the uniqueness? Moreover, I also concern if the optimal solution is unique, how to prove the convergence. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Strict convexity of $f$ over a convex feasible set insures that there is *at most one* optimal solution.  What happens if there is no optimal solution?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @BrianBorchers. Let's consider the case that there is at least one feasible solution to the constraints. Can I guarantee the convergence? and how to prove it?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I can also assume $f(x)$ is continuous, for example $f(x)=x^2$. I would like to know what techniques can be used to prove the convergence of a sequence of optimization problems.